# Method in Onstop doesn't execute properly in Android

Tags: android, json, save

I have coded a game that save some data in a JSON file. I want to save the data of the player before quitting the game.

In many topics on this forum read that it should be better if I do it in `onStop()` method so did like that:

I wrote a class that save players game in JSON file and called it on the `onStop()` method:

```
@Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SaveState.saveState(getApplicationContext());

}
```

But, in the log  we can see that the method is killed before the end of the loop.

I tried to set the method in a task but it's the same.

And now I don't know what to do!

The method in the other class looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GlobalVar.Done.size(); i++) {
    if (GlobalVar.Done.get(i)) {
        SaveJson.changejson(context, "savegame.json", Lvl, GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i), "Done", true);
        Log.i(SAV, "Saving done true : " + i + " id : " + GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i) + " Boolean : " + true);
    } else if (!GlobalVar.Done.get(i)) {

        StringBuilder sb0 = new StringBuilder(GlobalVar.TabStaterep[i].size());
        for (int c = 0; c < GlobalVar.TabStaterep[i].size(); c++) {
            sb0.append(GlobalVar.TabStaterep[i].get(c));

        }
        String str0 = sb0.toString();

        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(GlobalVar.TabStateClav[i].size());
        for (int c = 0; c < GlobalVar.TabStateClav[i].size(); c++) {
            sb1.append(GlobalVar.TabStateClav[i].get(c));

        }

        String str1 = sb1.toString();

        SaveJson.changejson(context, "savegame.json", Lvl, GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i), "Rep", str0);
        Log.i(SAV, "Saving rep : " + i + " id : " + GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i) + " Rep : " + str0);
        SaveJson.changejson(context, "savegame.json", Lvl, GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i), "Keyboard", str1);
        Log.i(SAV, "Saving keyboard : " + i + " id : " + GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i) + " Keyboard : " + str1);
        SaveJson.changejson(context, "savegame.json", Lvl, GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i), "Indice3", GlobalVar.Tabindice3.get(i));
        Log.i(SAV, "Saving indice 3 : " + i + " id : " + GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i) + " Indice3 : " + GlobalVar.Tabindice3.get(i));
        SaveJson.changejson(context, "savegame.json", Lvl, GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i), "Done", false);
        Log.i(SAV, "Saving done : " + i + " id : " + GlobalVar.LvlId.get(i) + " Done : " + false);
    }
}
```

Comment: in logcat you don't receive any exception?

Comment: no  exception in log cat

Comment: if the game just call onPause it also called Onstop and the method works fine but if i kill the app the method will be also killed ...